# tableView not showing the data in an array swift

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a `tableView` connected to the array. The array isn't empty but the `tableView` shows nothing other than lines. Can you help me, please?

```
var invoicesDictionary = [String:[String]]()
var invoicesSectionTitles = [String]()
var invoices: [String] =  ["JV1", "R1", "JV2"]

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for invoice in invoices {
        let invoiceKey = String(invoice.prefix(1))
        if var invoiceValues = self.invoicesDictionary[invoiceKey] {
            invoiceValues.append(invoice)
            self.invoicesDictionary[invoiceKey] = invoiceValues
        } else {
            self.invoicesDictionary[invoiceKey] = [invoice]
        }
    }

    invoicesSectionTitles = [String](invoicesDictionary.keys)
    invoicesSectionTitles = invoicesSectionTitles.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
    tableView.reloadData()

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return invoicesSectionTitles.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let invoiceKey = invoicesSectionTitles[section]
    if let invoiceValues = invoicesDictionary[invoiceKey] {
        return invoiceValues.count
    }
    return 0
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let invoiceKey = invoicesSectionTitles[indexPath.section]

    if let invoiceValues = invoicesDictionary[invoiceKey] {
        cell.textLabel?.text = invoiceValues[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return invoicesSectionTitles[section]
}

func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return invoicesSectionTitles
}
```

I printed out the array which is without a doubt not empty. I tried this code on an another project and it just worked.

Comment: set the tableview `delegate` and `datasource` in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Did you set the table view's delegate and data source to `self`?

Comment: Thank you it worked !

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this in viewDidLoad :

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the View controller that it's the delegate or assigned VC for the table View functionality by passing the following lines inside viewDidLoad()

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```